# Resend request parameters in ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf template that reads a URL parameter:

http://xxxx:8080/department?action=edit

In this way:

```
<input type="text" th:placeholder="#{department.id}" class="form-control" th:field="*{id}" th:readonly="${param.action[0] == 'edit'}">
```

Basically this let's you edit if action=edit is in the URL. This works fine, but when I handle the POST method, the modelAndView redirect to /departent alone without the parameters when there are errors:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/department", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView department(HttpServletRequest request, @Valid Department department,
                               BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        // data with errores, try again
        modelAndView.setViewName("department");
    } else {
        // all ok. Save and continue
        departmentService.updateDepartment(department);
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:departments");
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

When the page reload, I have the following error message:

***Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "param.action[0] == 'edit'" (template: "department" - line 24, col 103)***

The reason is that the new URL is:

http://xxxx:8080/department

The think that I need to use a URL parameters is because the link is generated by A HREF link.

I've tried:

```
modelAndView.getModelMap().put("action", "edit");
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify this by making `param.action[0] == 'edit'` a variable and simply adding that to the model.  Like:

`model.addAttribute("isReadOnly", someVariableHereThatMakesItReadOnly);`

and

`th:readonly="${isReadOnly}"` in your form.

This makes your view less complex and allows you to unit test the value of `isReadOnly` on the server-side.  Then you can do:

```
@PostMapping("/department")
public String postDepartment(@Valid Department department,
                             BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        //add error information here
        model.addAttribute("isReadOnly", true); 
        return "department"
    } 
    departmentService.updateDepartment(department);
    return "redirect:/departments";
}
```

There are likely multiple ways you can do this.  This is just one way.

You could also probably do `return "redirect:/department?action=edit"` in your post method, but then you'd need to get creative about how to display any error messages.

Comment: Thanks! I did just thank. I made 2 controller(one for edit, one for new) that add the new flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change too much your code, you add to html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="requestedAction" th:value="${param.action[0]}">
```

And change the RequestMapping method to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/department", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView department(HttpServletRequest request, @Valid Department department, BindingResult bindingResult, @RequestParam String requestedAction) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        // data with errores, try again
        modelAndView.setViewName("department?action=" + requestedAction);
    } else {
        // all ok. Save and continue
        departmentService.updateDepartment(department);
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:departments");
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
```